# Duplicate empty header occur in datatable when enabling scrollX or scrollY when using Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a datatable in my program. And I want it to be scrollable horizontally so  what I did was like this:

```
var tableI = $('#table_data').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "scrollX": true,
     "dom": 'frtp'
});
```

It came out like this(as sample output):
[image]

It doubled the header. How am I going to fix this?

EDIT:
Here's another sample:
[image]

here's my HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="act_data" width="100%">  <div style="float:left;width:385px" >
    <button type="button" id="edit_acc" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editAcc"><span class=" fa fa-edit "> Edit Account</span></button>
      <button type="button" id="de_act" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeAcc"><span class=" fa fa-edit "> Activate/Deactivate</span></button>
      <!-- <button type="button" id="refresh" class="btn btn-link"  data-target="#DeAcc"><span class="fa fa-refresh"></span></button>-->
      <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/homeAdmin/homepage')?>?id=6" class="btn btn-link"><span class="fa fa-refresh"></a>
    </div><thead class="header">
      <tr class="well">
        <th style="font-size: 14px;">Employee ID#</th>
        <th style="font-size: 14px;">Username</th>
        <th style="font-size: 14px;">Account Type</th>
        <th style="font-size: 14px;">Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <?php if($result != NULL){?>
        <?php foreach($result as $row){ ?>
            <tr>
               <td style="font-size: 15px;padding-left: 20px;">
                   <?php echo $row->employeeID;?>
                   <input type="hidden" name="userID" id="userID" value="<?php  echo $row->userID;?>" />
                   <input type="hidden" name="pass" id="pass" value="<?php  echo $row->password;?>" />

              </td>

              <td style="font-size: 15px;padding-left: 20px;">
                   <?php echo $row->username;?>
              </td>
              <td style="font-size: 15px;padding-left: 20px;">
                   <?php echo $row->usertype;?>
              </td>
              <td style="font-size: 15px;padding-left: 20px;">
               <?php echo $row->status; ?>
               </td>

          </tr>
        <?php }?>
      <?php }?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Can you fiddle it with some static data?

Comment: @MokshShah, I added another sample in my question..

Comment: How does the markup (HTML) looks like?

Comment: @davidkonrad, please see added html code in the question.. thanks :)

Comment: Why do you have a div inside of a table? Not sure if it's related but you should put that outside the table.

Comment: @user3779812, It's because I want those buttons to be aligned with the search textfield of the datatable.. But I will try to remove it to test if it does affect to the dataTable.. thanks for suggesting :)

Comment: @user3779812, I tried to remove it as what you have said but it's still the same.. :(

Comment: It seems to work -> **http://jsfiddle.net/m8x1nw8k/** (here stripped for PHP). The only thing is that you are refering to `table_data` while the table id is `act_data` ...

Comment: @davidkonrad.. It didn't work on me.. I mean, yes I can show the datatable like what you have shown in here jsfiddle.net/m8x1nw8k and it is also scrollable horizontally but still the header duplicated like in the other example I have given..

Answer (score 27):

I had the same issue with firefox & firefox developer edition. The root cause is, when we set `scrollX:true`, datatable adds an additional div with a table and a header inside, apart from the table & header already constructed. This is to get the scrolling within table effect.

Datatable, tries to set the height to 0px, to hide it. Some browsers don't interpret this properly.

```
<tr style="height: 0px;" role="row">
```

To hide it, changing the style to this row to 'hidden' will break the structure of the table. The working solution would be, to have `visibility:'collapse'`

Sample datatable configuration:

```
tableElement.DataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        $('.dataTables_scrollBody thead tr').css({visibility:'collapse'});
    }
    //other datatable configurations...  
});
```

since it's a table, we need to have `visibility:'collapse'` and not `visibility:'hidden'` - more info on [visibility css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

Comment: I have been dealing with this issue all day and to get it to work I had to use the 'drawCallback' config property not the 'initComplete' config property to get it to work. So: drawCallback: function () {             $('.dataTables_scrollBody thead tr').css({ visibility: 'collapse' });
        }

Comment: i had the very same problem. Your solution indeed made the duplicate header row disappear but now the table headers are misaligned with the actual data. Any clue? thanks

Comment: I had to put this on both initComplete and drawCallback

Comment: Yes I put it in initComplete and then also listen to the `draw.dt` event, which is like the drawCallback function. Thanks for sharing this answer!

Comment: it worked but it reappears when we resize  or try to add `fixedColumns` options of datatable

Answer (score 10):

**Solution 1 :**

To Resolve This Please Use `"scrollXInner": true`  Avoid to Using `"scrollX": true"`

```
var tableI = $('#table_data').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "scrollX": true, //Do Not Use This (Remove This Line)
    "scrollXInner": true //Use This (Add This Line)
     "dom": 'frtp'
});
```

**Solution 2 :**

OR You Can Add This `CSS`

```
.dataTables_scrollBody thead tr[role="row"]{
    visibility: collapse !important;
}
```

Comment: Solution 2 works for me. However, it leaves a space between the header and the scrollable body, so you need to add this also in the css:          

    .dataTables_scrollHeadInner table{ margin-bottom: 0px !important; }

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on Google Chrome. This was the fix:

```
.dataTable(
{
  "processing": false,
  "serverSide": false,
  "autoWidth": true,
  "columnDefs": [
    {"orderable": false, "targets": [5, 6]}
  ],
  "order": [1, 'asc'],
  "dom": 'l<"toolbar">frtip',
  drawCallback: function () { // this gets rid of duplicate headers
      $('.dataTables_scrollBody thead tr').css({ display: 'none' }); 
  },
  scrollY: '65vh',
  scrollCollapse: true,
  paging: false
});
```

Comment: This fixed it for my Chrome.

Comment: If the display is set to none, the column width is not matched with the first header, so use ```visibility:'collapse'``` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The solution was simple in my case. Just include this on your css:

```
/* Override sorting header --> DataTable Bug */
.dataTables_scrollBody > table > thead > tr {
    visibility: collapse;
    height: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Good explanation by Sairam. Better way would be to use just a CSS

```
div.dataTables_scrollBody thead {           
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This hides the second header and removes the white space between the header and body.

```
<style>
     .dataTables_scrollBody thead tr {
         visibility: collapse;
     }

     .dataTables_scrollBody {
         margin-top: -10px;
      }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

"scrollX": '100%',

"scrollXInner": '125%',

Comment: The duplicate header still there.. :(

Comment: I just noticed that if I use mozilla firefox, the duplicate header is not there, but when I use google chrome, the duplicate header is there..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$('#DataTables_Table_0').on( 'draw.dt' function() {
    $('.dataTables_scrollBody thead tr').addClass('hidden')
}
```

Reference: [geam's March 2015 answer on datatables.net forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20507/duplicate-header-rows-appear-when-using-sscrollx-option-in-datetable#)

Comment: This caused my header row and body columns to not line up. The CSS that works is `visibilty: collapse;` from Sairam Krish's answer.

Comment: @ChuckL : thanks for the update; although I had moved onto bootstrap tables instead because of the buggy nature of dataTables like this. Even my header and body columns got misaligned and on every second refresh, they got aligned back automatically?! Didnot debug it then.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use

```
dataTable.columns.adjust();
```

on init/draw callback

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript file Add below the line.  serverSide: true, processing: true, scrollX : "100%",  Add the Below code to your page.  .dataTables_scrollBody thead tr[role="row"]{     visibility: collapse !important; }

Comment: You should format the code snippets in your answer using the Markdown syntax available (it even allows you to tell which programming language you're using). Please consult the syntax so you can make your answer clearer to all who read it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Following code in your CSS:

```
div.dataTables_scrollHeadInner table { margin-bottom: 0px !important; }
```