# Is there a way to avoid datatable resizing?

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Is there a way to avoid datatable resizing? Especially, if for example, the default number of rows for each page in the datatable is only 10 rows. So, if you are going to fed 13 rows in the datatable that makes it 2 pages. 10 rows for the first page and 3 rows in the second page. So now, since there are only 3 rows in the second page, the table will automatically resize and will now be so short unlike in the first page. As a result, the position of datatable pagination will also be changed. What I want is that, there will be no changes in the datatable's height so that the position of datatable page will not be changed too.

What I have tried is adding attribute `height` in the `<table>` tag.. But the result is not good..

Comment: Sorry, but there are too many unclear elements in your question.  You're talking about paging of data, then you're talking about fixed positions.  You need to edit your questions and be very specific about your requirements, and what you've already tried to solve it yourself

Comment: @freefaller, I have already edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have a tricky solution. I have done in one of my [demo](http://coderexample.com/datatable-scroller-server-side/) project.
modify your code at the time of initialization like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable =  $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
        scrollY: 200,
    } );
});
```

then add this css in your document.

```
.dataTables_scrollBody{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: you mean, i'll just have to get rid of the pagination?

Comment: oh, I get it now.. but there's problem like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226283/datatable-scrollx-error whenever I add sroller.. I thought it will just occur in the scrollX. But I tried the scrollY and the same problem occured.